# Netbeans java creating jar

Tags: java, class, netbeans, jar, jaas

I need your help! 
I have some classes and I have to create in Netbeans a jar file for all of them. 
Someone have any idea? 
Thank you very much

Comment: I have an idea. Google it :)

Comment: Push the button that says "build project" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the project node, select "clean and build".

Once completed, the `Jar` file will be located in the `dist` folder of your project folder

Comment: No, I'm sorry I mean, I have to create a Jar for each class! Thankyou

Comment: You either have to do it manually or make a project for each class

Comment: have you any experiences to work with jaas in eclipse/netbeans ? accomplished to the oracle tutorial I have to create this jars